# Is there a precedent for casting the same actor in an American remake of a British/foreign television show?

Tags: first-appearance, casting, remake

Broadchurch (ITV/BBC America) was my favorite television show, specifically crime drama, in 2013. FOX is remaking the series but changed the name to Gracepoint. Interestingly, they cast David Tennant, the male lead DI Alec Hardy in Broadchurch, as the male lead/character equivalent in Gracepoint, Emmett Carter.

I've watched plenty of foreign shows and at least see trailers for their American remakes, but have never encountered this practice. Has this been done before? Is it common?

Comment: Not a TV show, but *Death at a Funeral* cast Peter Dinklage in exactly the same role in the 2007 UK original and the 2010 US remake.

Comment: Now that's a serious audition!

Comment: Close but not quite: Strike Back. Started as a British series on Sky1 with Richard Armitage playing John Porter in 2010/2011. When the series was picked up for a 'second season', Armitage was no longer available due to playing a Hobbit. The character was kidnapped and two new leads were cast, one American and one Brit. The series was a joint creation, aired both on Sky1 in the UK and Cinemax in America. While he was not a regular, he did appear as Sgt Porter in two of the second series episodes as a sort of cameo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's quite a rare occurrence, with two major exceptions: comedies and factual programmes.

**Comedy remakes**:

- **[Red Dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf)** which was [remade in the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf#U.S._version) (one pilot episode) with [Robert Llewellyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Llewellyn) as [Kryten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryten) in both versions, and he was also joined by the original series writers, [Rob Grant and Doug Naylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant_Naylor).
- **[The IT Crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd)** also suffered a [US pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd#American_version) in which [Richard Ayoade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Ayoade) reprised his role as [Moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_IT_Crowd_characters#Maurice_Moss).
- **[Max Headroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom_%28TV_series%29)** was an American series based on a British TV pilot [Max Headroom: 20 Minutes into the Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom:_20_Minutes_into_the_Future) which starred [Matt Frewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Frewer) as the title character in both versions.
- **[Little Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Britain)** was re-made/continued as [Little Britain USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Britain_USA) which starred both [Matt Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Lucas) and [David Walliams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Walliams) as nearly every role.
- [**Da Ali G Show**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Ali_G_Show) with [Sacha Baron Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacha_Baron_Cohen) as [Ali G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_G). Season 1 was produced by Channel 4 and sold to HBO, Season 2 (*Ali G in da USAiii*) was produced by HBO and sold to Channel 4.
- [**Whose Line Is It Anyway?**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whose_Line_Is_It_Anyway%3F) shared several panellists in common with the [US version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whose_Line_Is_It_Anyway%3F_%28U.S._TV_series%29); [Ryan Stiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Stiles), [Colin Mochrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Mochrie) and to a lesser extent [Wayne Brady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Brady).
- [**Wilfred**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfred_%28U.S._TV_series%29) is a remake of the [Australian series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfred_%28Australian_TV_series%29) which both star [Jason Gann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Gann) as Wilfred.

**Factual remakes**:

- [**The Weakest Link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Weakest_Link) was hosted by Anne Robinson in the original and [US remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakest_Link_%28U.S._game_show%29).
- **[Distraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distraction_%28game_show%29)** was hosted by Jimmy Carr in both the original and [US remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distraction_%28game_show%29#International_versions) of the show.
- [Gordon Ramsay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Ramsay) started in the [British **Hell's Kitchen**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Kitchen_%28UK_TV_series%29) in 2004 for one season before going to the US to present [the remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Kitchen_%28US_TV_series%29) in 2005.
- **[How Clean Is Your House?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Clean_Is_Your_House%3F)** was [remade in the US](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0439370/) with Kim & Aggie presenting both.
- **[Pop Idol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_Idol)** / **[American Idol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Idol)** with [Simon Cowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Cowell) as a judge.
- [**The X Factor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X_Factor_(UK)) was also [remade in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X_Factor_(U.S.)) with Simon Cowell.
- The talk show [**Trisha Goddard**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisha_Goddard_%28TV_series%29) was remade in America as [**The Trisha Goddard Show**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trisha_Goddard_Show)
- [**Supernanny**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernanny) with [Jo Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo_Frost) in the UK and [US version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429442/).

It also less commonly happens the other way around, though most of the examples I can find are American shows which were hosted by British actors before being remade in Britain:

- [**America's Got Talent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America%27s_Got_Talent) was remade in the UK as **[Britain's Got Talent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britain%27s_Got_Talent)**, with [Piers Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Morgan) judging both.
- **So You Think You Can Dance** is hosted by [Cat Deeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_Deeley) in the [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_You_Think_You_Can_Dance_%28United_States%29) and [UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_You_Think_You_Can_Dance_%28UK_TV_series%29) versions.
- [**The Taste**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taste) was [remade in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taste_%28UK_TV_series%29) with the same judges; [Anthony Bourdain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Bourdain), [Nigella Lawson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigella_Lawson) and [Ludo Lefebvre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludo_Lefebvre)

In both cases its easy to see why: the cast hold together the show and are usually the ones responsible for making the show famous, so it's a no-brainer that you want to get as many of them as possible to help sell your show, especially if they're the only presenter.

---

See also:

- [Foreign Remakes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForeignRemake) on TVTropes
- [Remake Cameo](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RemakeCameo) on TVTropes
- [Category:American television series based on Australian television series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:American_television_series_based_on_Australian_television_series) on Wikipedia
- [List of American television series based on British television series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_television_series_based_on_British_television_series) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 6):

Anthony Stewart Head, famous for playing Giles on *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*, plays the character of Stephen Caudwell on [Free Agents](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1330768/), the foul-mouthed head of the advertising agency.

Two years later, the show was [remade in the US](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1839481/) with Hank Azaria and Kathryn Hahn instead of Stephen Mangan and Sharon Horgan, and some other changes to characters and plotlines, but one thing remained the same - Anthony Head still played the same role of Stephen, head of the agency.

Of course, American network TV being what it is, he was significantly toned down in obnoxiousness and vulgarity.

Answer (score 1):

The UK series [Ultraviolet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169501/) (late 90's Vampire series) featured Idris Elba.

He was cast in the unaired pilot episode of a US remake (as the same character).